# Using only one query to return team within a project list?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to return the team members assigned to a project. If I have a project list like so:

```
SELECT * FROM projects
```

Which displays up to 10 projects per page.

I then want to display the team members assigned to these projects. The members are stored like:

```
SELECT * FROM project_members WHERE projectid = X
```

So if I have a table of results which list the projects, is there a way to also pull all the project members at the same time. Or is this best done using two queries? If it is possible to do with one query, how do I loop through them within a list of projects too. I'm using PHP to handle everything.

I.e my PHP code right now would be:

```
<?php 

foreach($projects as $project) {
    // Display project

    $members = $this->project_model->get_project_members($project->ID);
    foreach($members as $member) {
       // Display
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM ((SELECT * FROM `projects` LIMIT 10) p)
INNER JOIN `project_members` pm ON `pm`.`projectid` = `p`.`id`
```

Comment: Hi that's great! How would I loop through this then and display correctly in PHP code? I'm just having trouble visualizing it at the moment.

Comment: For example $currentProjectId = null;
        foreach($result as $row) {
            
            if ($row['project_id'] != $currentProjectId) {
                echo 'Project ', $row['project_id'], '<br/>';
                $currentProjectId = $row['project_id'];
            }
            
            echo $row['project_member_name'], '<br/>';
        }

Answer (score 0):

Use `INNER JOIN` and combine query.

```
SELECT P.* FROM projects P
INNER JOIN project_members PM ON P.id = PM.projectid
```